# How do I connect to remote server in bash?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, samba, smb

[image]

[image]

The connection works fine with doing it through the gui as shown in pic 1, but I have tried

```
mount_smbfs //rajohns:MyPassword@msclst2fs
```

and I see that the format is supposed to be

```
//[domain;][user[:password]@]server[/share] path
```

but I don't know what to put for `domain` or `/share` or `path`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
mount_smbfs rajohns:MyPassword@msclst2fs/SHARE2 /Volumes/msclst2fs
```

to make the volume available at `/mnt/msclst2fs`. The path is wherever in your file system you want to make the volume accessible.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It is saying `mount_smbfs: could not find mount point /Volumes/msclst2fs: No such file or directory` when attempting your command.

Comment: mount_smbfs requires that the mount point already exist. it will not created it for you. so you will need to `mkdir /Volumes/msclst2fs`   but this I think can cause issues when using the gui.

Comment: ok thanks guys I was able to get it to work using `mkdir /Volumes/SHARE2` and then `mount_smbfs //rajohns:MyPassword@msclst2fs/SHARE2 /Volumes/SHARE2`

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't tested this, and misremembered how the `mount_*` programs worked (I was thinking the trailing component was created on the fly and deleted on unmounting; `/Volumes` would need to exist but does by default in Mac OS X).